# How do I change the display of the number zero in Mac Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, character, zsh

My question arises from the terminal response to commands like cal and date.

I'm using a typeface where the default zero is a standard open zero. In other applications, such as Pages, this can be changed to a zero with a slash through it, or a zero with a dot in the middle, via Command T > Typography > Typographic Extras, and checking e.g. "Slashed Zero".

In Terminal, I'm finding that checking "Slashed Zero" has no effect. Commands like cal and date continue to return an open zero.

How can I make this change? Thanks.

Comment: This is generally just determined by what font the Terminal is using (which is controlled by what you have selected in the Terminal preferences).

Comment: Terminal configuration questions should be posted at [su]. In your case, the solution is simple: The Terminal App allows in its preferences the font to be used. You just needs to choose a font where the zero looks like your taste. Also, pay attention to how `1` and `l` look; they are also difficult to distinguish in some fonts.

Comment: As far as I know, Terminal doesn't *have* any such typographic settings. The font might *provide* both types of 0s, but Terminal doesn't provide access to them.

Comment: @chepner Terminal does indeed have typographic settings. They are at Preferences > Profiles > Font Change. See the symbol on the upper left of the box? Click on it.

Comment: @user1934428 It appears that you are also unaware of Terminal's typography setting.  Most, if not all, of the monospace fonts created for coding in the last decade have two forms of zero, and some have three. Examples: Input Mono, Fira Mono/Fira Code, IBM Plex Mono, Microsoft Cascadia Mono, Operator Mono, JetBrains Mono and Apple's own SF Mono. There has to be a way to choose between the forms of zero for general terminal use and for an editor like Vim.

Comment: They have different encodings. A Terminal application doing this would have to do font substitution, with the effect that if you copy something from the terminal to a different application, you would copy the substituted font! Think of the trouble this would cause, if you copied this into your text editor into a program you are writing. Even if your Terminal would provide this feature (I don't think it does), you are safer to use a font where the glyph for the code representing a zero, already looks the way you want.

Comment: @redge : BTW, if you want to solve this using a change in the Terminal configuration (instead of catching the output from your application and translate the font programmatically), may I suggest that you post this in [su] or in [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), because Stackoverflow is intended for discussing programming questions.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks, but I'm looking for an answer to my question, not for advice on what I need and don't need, or for speculation about whether Terminal will do what its own menu, which you were evidently unaware of, says it will do.

Comment: @redge OK, I see where you found Slashed Zero now. I can see that whether you have the option to check it depends on the selected font, but I also can see that checking it when it *is* provided does nothing (at least with JetBrains Mono). I wonder if it's still a font-specific issue (maybe the font is incorrectly reporting that it *has* slashed zeros?), but I really don't have an answer.

Comment: The broader question is support for the three forms of the zero character (open, slashed, dotted) in terminals and code editors. It looks to be clear that the Mac Terminal.app, and probably most others, if not all, have no support for OpenType features. This means that the font's default zero, whatever it is, will prevail. Some code editors, such as VS Code, have begun to support alternative zeros. There's some useful discussion about this on GitHub in relation to the JetBrains Mono font repository.